# find multiple edges given 2 vertices in BOOST graph

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I am using Boost Graph library for some project and i want to find number of times an edge is repeated in a graph. for example,

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, Node_Info, Edge_Info > Graph_t;  
//node_info and Edge_info are external node and edge properties (structures)
```

suppose if i have two nodes, node1 and node2 and there is an edge between them (node1, node2). edge property for each edge contains a timestamp start, end.. and there can be many such edges in the graph with different timestamps. for example.

```
edge1 = (node1, node2) with start = 100, end = 200.
edge2 = (node1, node2) with start = 250, end = 400.
```

I know that in a boost graph, given two vertices, we can find whether an edge exists in the graph or not using the following.

```
std::pair < edge_t, bool > p = boost::edge( node1, node2, myGraph );
if(p.second == 1)  cout << "edge exists!" << endl;
else cout << " does not exist " << endl;
```

But this could mean that it would only return any one edge even if multiple edges exist  with different edge properties --> PROBLEM

can anyone suggest an idea how to get such multiple edges between two given nodes? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

1) Just check the out-edges for all that go to the desired target:

```
boost::graph_traits<Graph_t>::out_edge_iterator ei, ei_end;
boost::tie(ei, ei_end) = out_edges( node1, myGraph );
int parallel_count = 0;
for( ; ei != ei_end; ++ei) {
  if( target(*ei, myGraph) == node2 ) {
    cout << "Found edge (node1, node2) with property: " << myGraph[*ei] << endl;
    ++parallel_count;
  };
};
cout << "There are a total of " << parallel_count << " parallel edges." << endl;
```

2) Specify `boost::multisetS` as the `OutEdgeListS` template argument to `adjacency_list`, this will enable an extra function called `edge_range` which returns a range of iterators for all the "parallel" edges coming out of `u` and going into `v`, as the [documentation page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html) states:

> ```
> std::pair<out_edge_iterator, out_edge_iterator>
> edge_range(vertex_descriptor u, vertex_descriptor v,
>            const adjacency_list& g)
> ```
>
> Returns a pair of out-edge iterators that give the range for all the parallel edges from u to v. This function only works when the OutEdgeList for the adjacency_list is a container that sorts the out edges according to target vertex, and allows for parallel edges. The multisetS selector chooses such a container.

The reason why this function is only available for `multisetS` is because in order to provide (easily) a range of iterators to parallel edges, you need the edges to be grouped together, which is the case for `multisetS` because they are sorted by vertex-descriptor, and therefore, all parallel out-edges are grouped together. That's the only container choice that will give you this, otherwise, you have to use option (1) (note: creating a `filter_iterator` (see [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html)) could come in handy if you really use this a lot).

Comment: hi Mikael, I just posted an answer below where I am stuck up a bit. could you please suggest?