# modify filter_iterator predicate to accept two arguments (binary fn) in BOOST

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, bind, boost-graph

with reference to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214091/find-multiple-edges-given-2-vertices-in-boost-graph), how do i pass another argument to the predicate. for example here is the code snippet.

```
    // want this to take 2 arguments instead of one. (like a binary function)
    template < typename edge >
    struct isRequiredEdge {
    bool operator()( edge& e) {
    return true;
    }
    };

    // out_edge_iterators
    out_edge_it beg, end;
    boost::tie(beg, end) = boost::out_edges( v, G);
    typedef boost::filter_iterator< isRequiredEdge<ed_t>, out_edge_it > FilterIter;


    isRequiredEdge<ed_t> predicate;
    FilterIter ffirst ( predicate, beg, end  );
    FilterIter llast  ( predicate, end  );


    std::copy( ffirst, llast, std::ostream_iterator< ed_t > (std::cout, "  " ) );
```

In the above code, it takes only one argument ( as edge_descriptor ). I want to pass a logic variable, say for example an int to the predicate, and compare the edge property of the edge with the int and return true or false accordingly. I know how to access edge property, but i am unable to pass the 2nd parameter to the predicate. I am aware it is a unary predicate, but unable to bind the 2nd argument to it through ptr_fun or bind2nd. Could anyone suggest ?

I am able to print all the edges, but without the actual logic inserted in the above predicate, as once can notice above.

---

here is my functor:

```
    template < typename edge, typename graph >
    struct isRequiredEdge {
    isRequiredEdge( int t, graph& G ) : m_t(t), m_G(G) { }
    bool operator()( edge e ) {
    cout << " edge " << e << ": t = " << m_t  << endl;
    EdgeInfo* ei = &boost::get(EdgeInfoPropertyTag (), m_G, e ); 
    if(ei->time == m_t)
            return true;
    else 
          return false;
    }
    private:
       int m_t;
       graph m_G;

    };

    // out_edge_iterator
    boost::tie(beg, end) = boost::out_edges(*inf_it, G);

    // typedef filter_iterator for type out_edge_it
    typedef boost::filter_iterator< isRequiredEdge<ed_t, Graph>, out_edge_it > FilterIter;

    // create predicate object passing parameters such as time t and graph G.
    isRequiredEdge<ed_t, Graph> predicate(t, G);

    // define iterators here
    FilterIter ffirst ( predicate, beg, end  );
    FilterIter llast  ( predicate, end  );
    std::copy( ffirst, llast, std::ostream_iterator< ed_t > (std::cout, " " ) );
```

when ffirst is created, the functor works correctly and output is as expected. 
when **llast** is created, the functor tries to get information for any random edge which does not exist in the graph ( boost::get(NodeInfoPropertyTag ( ) ) due to which seg fault happens.

Any suggestions how do i create llast without this happening?

Comment: So the problem is that you don't know how to bind the functor properly?

Comment: yes, below is my functor code, i get seg fault when llast is initialized. any idea how do i bypass this for llast ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert you functor to accept two arguments, then use `std::bind`, or boost bind to return you a functor where one of the arguments is bound to the value you want. Pass this to you iteration.

For example, if you change your functor signature to,

```
Operator()(int v, edge& e)
```

Then your bind becomes

```
auto f = std::bind(isRequiredEdge<>::operator(), &predicate, 42, _1);
```

`_1` is a placeholder for the argument to be passed in.

Note, you can replace all the std stuff with boost in the above snippet, if you don't have c++11.

Comment: I did modify the functor to the following, but i am getting this segmentation fault which i know where it happens, but unable to fix it. please see description to the question in below answer